# Stieltjes Integral - If $f, f^2, g, g^2\in R(\alpha)$ for an arbitrary integrator $\alpha$, then is $fg\in R(\alpha)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

My question is if $f, f^2, g, g^2\in R(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$ for an arbitrary integrator $\alpha$, then is $fg\in R(\alpha)$ as well?

This question stemmed from a problem in Apostol's Analysis, in which $f, f^2, g, g^2\in R(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$ is assumed, and I have to prove an identity that involves the term $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)d{\alpha(x)}$, so I was wondering how the existence of this integral is guaranteed when there is no assumption that the integrator $\alpha$ is of bounded variation (in which case only $f,g\in R(\alpha)$ would be enough.

This is the original problem.

If $f, f^2, g, g^2\in R(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$, prove that 
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_a^b[\int_a^b \begin{vmatrix}
        f(x) & g(x) \\
        f(y) & g(y) \\
        \end{vmatrix} d{\alpha(y)}]d{\alpha(x)}
=(\int_a^b f(x)^2d{\alpha(x)})(\int_a^b g(x)^2d{\alpha(x)})-(\int_a^b f(x)g(x)d{\alpha(x)})^2$$

When $\alpha$ is increasing on $[a,b]$, deduce the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Is this just a mistake from the author or a fact that follows from the above assumptions? I would appreciate if anyone could explain this to me.

Comment: Does the identity $fg = \frac{1}{2}[(f+g)^2-f^2-g^2]$ help?

Comment: I've thought of that but then how do I know that $(f+g)^2\in R(\alpha)$?

Comment: Doesn't it follow from $|fg| \leq f^2 + g^2$?

Comment: I put in the original problem. @PedroM. Isn't comparability only guaranteed to follow in the case of increasing integrators?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you're right. Even comparing on both sides via $\min(f^2,g^2) \leq |fg| \leq \max(f^2,g^2)$ might not be enough. Good question!